# How to use the new cycles mist pass in 2.68?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How to make cycles mist work in 2.68?
I turned on the render pass, then fiddled with the start and depth settings in *Properties > World > Mist Pass*, but with no result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not much [documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Passes) yet, but it looks like you could use it in the compositor to get a mist/fading effect.

[image]

just straight, it returns a black and white map based on the settings in *Properties > World  > Mist*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can investigate this simple tutorial. It's only a few steps and you're ready to go with mist pass. By the way - great feature, we don't have to go back to blender render to set it up.
http://blog.yamandi.com/mist-pass-blender-268-how-use-it-cycles

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Please see the _Provide context for links_ section of the [How do I write a good answer? page](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and make the appropriate edits to your answer.